# How to disable Html table native selection in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, html-table

I have a "problem" in firefox, it has a native selection in html table when you press Ctrl :

[image: firefox table selection]

how can I remove this action so mine can works?

Thanks :) !

Comment: Hijack click event and `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: Refer this https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-selectable-disable-ctrl-in-a-table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is easy, just call the

```
e.preventDefault()
```

function on the click or mouseDown event.